# Shell - Read from file & extract ticket ID from each line line & add to the end of the line

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to read from a file (output.txt), extract the ticket number in the file names from each line and add to the end of the line.

The difficulty is, the ticket number maybe any kind of number, and there are some which are not considered as ticket number and they do not have a fixed format.

But what I know is, before the ticket number, it usually have either `_` or `.` and behind it is always `_`

For example:

1. SM-10880B1
2. LSUFE-583B1
3. PCRF-17717B1
4. REQUEST-6771B1
5. SM-10507B1
6. ECS-6870B1

Sample file names

```
    patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar
    patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar
    patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar
    patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jar
    patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar
    InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar
    patch_FW_9.3.0.1B_x86_64.jar  <-- not to extract, 1B is not the ticket number
    patch_SW_4.2.1_5B1_x86_64.jar <-- not to extract, 5B1 is not the ticket number
    patch_SW_9.3.0.ServicePackB1_x86_64.jar <-- not to extract, ServicePackB1 is not the ticket number
```

Text file (output.txt)

```
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/A/patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/B/patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/C/patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/D/patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jar,patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jarr,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/E/patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar,patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/F/InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar,InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar,InstallPackage
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/G/build.x86_64/_dist/image/patch_SW_9.3.0.1B_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_9.3.0.1B_x86_64.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW4/releases/H/build.x86_64/_dist/image/patch_SW_4.2.1_5B1_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_4.2.1_5B1_x86_64.jar,patch
    /home/mobaxterm/Data/SW/SW9/releases/I/build.x86_64/_dist/image/patch_SW_9.3.0.ServicePackB1_x86_64.jar,patch_SW_9.3.0.ServicePackB1_x86_64.jar,patch
```

Desired output

```
    patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar,SM-10880B1
    patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar,LSUFE-583B1
    patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar,PCRF-17717B1
    patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jar,REQUEST-6771B1
    patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar,ECS-6870B1
    InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar,SM-10507B1
```

Comment: Tried using sed to grab the pattern which I can look for, but still, like I said, the format is not fixed.  I didn't bother to post the script at all as it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on what's provided, there is not enough information to provide a suggestion. The delimiters (_,.) aren't enough.. I would suggest searching for a format in the ticket. Who generates the file names (ticket numbers) ? Is the set of prefixes limited (SM, LSUFE, REQUEST ..)  or can it be anything ? Is the prefix mandatory ?  Does "B1" have any significance (it is at the end of each example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the syntax to POSIX, you can make use of the `expr text : regex` expression to parse the `tickets` from the line and then write each `line` for which there is a valid ticket out followed by a comma `','` and the `ticket`. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
    new=$(expr "$line" : "^.*[_.]\([A-Z]*[-][a-zA-Z0-9]*\)_.*$")
    [ -n "$new" ] && printf "%s,%s\n" "$line" "$new"
done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$cat dat/ticketno.dat
patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar
patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar
patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar
patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jar
patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar
InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar
patch_FW_9.3.0.1B_x86_64.jar  <-- not to extract, 1B is not the ticket number
patch_SW_4.2.1_5B1_x86_64.jar <-- not to extract, 5B1 is not the ticket number
patch_SW_9.3.0.ServicePackB1_x86_64.jar <-- not to extract, ServicePackB1 is not the ticket number
```

**Output**

```
$ sh ticketno.sh dat/ticketno.dat
patch_SW_9.3.0.SM-10880B1_HW_client_x86_64.jar,SM-10880B1
patch_SW_9.3.1.LSUFE-583B1_x86_64.jar,LSUFE-583B1
patch_SW_9.3.0_PCRF-17717B1_x86_64.jar,PCRF-17717B1
patch_SW_9.3.0_REQUEST-6771B1_i86pc.jar,REQUEST-6771B1
patch_CM_9_ECS-6870B1_i86pc.jar,ECS-6870B1
InstallPackage_SW_9.3.0.SM-10507B1_20150821_sun4u64.jar,SM-10507B1
```